# Creating menu viewcontroller

Tags: ios, menu

I need to create a menu viewcontroller similar to the following screen.
[image]

Are there any sample libraries. I searched but couldn't find. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [RESideMenu](https://github.com/romaonthego/RESideMenu)

[image]

You need to do some changes:

- You need to replace background image(*Stars*) from AppDelegate's method `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of `DEMOAppDelegate`.
- Change menu and icons from `DEMOLeftMenuViewController`

Comment: Tnx for the answer. How to replace the background image.

Comment: Add your image in project and replace image name from `DEMOAppDelegate.m` file. Check old image name is `Stars`.